# Access session bean by its name without JNDI-Lookup

Tags: jakarta-ee, glassfish, ejb, spring-el

I want to write a custom [BeanResolver](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.2.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/expression/BeanResolver.html) for the Spring Expression Language to resolve EJBs in expressions (for example `"@MyBean.property=='example-value'"`). How can I retrieve a bean by its name without doing a JNDI-Lookup? Do I have to write a plugin for the application server of my choice (which would be glassfish)?

Comment: Why is it necessary to retrieve the bean without doing a JNDI lookup?  Injection and JNDI lookup are the entry points into all EJBs.

Comment: Because my goal is to inject the bean by its name without actually using the @EJB-Annotations. Given that the user hasn't configured a JNDI-Name (via `mappedName` for example), I can in fact define a vendor specific mapper function that determines the real bean name. But this approach won't work if the developers do assign custom JNDI names for the bean that differ from the actual bean name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EE injection and JNDI lookup are the entry point to all EJBs; there is no other standard way to obtain an instance of an EJB.  If you're using EJB 3.1, the bindings in `java:global`, `java:app`, and `java:module` are well-defined and cannot be changed by a developer.

```
java:global/MyApp/MyModule/MyBean!com.example.MyIntf
java:app/MyModule/MyBean!com.example.MyIntf
java:module/MyBean!com.example.MyIntf
```

This is effectively locating an EJB by name.  (It does require JNDI, but it's not clear from your description why JNDI itself would be problematic, though I do understand why bindings are a problem.) If you know that the EJB only supports one interface, you can omit the `!com.example.MyIntf`.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer, this helped me a lot. There was some confusion on my side regarding the concepts of Interfaces and your answer delivered a good hint. Additional reading of the relevant parts of JSR-318 and the Java EE 6 Tutorial helped me on, too.

Comment: From my current knowledge a JNDI-Lookup won't be a problem anymore. It looks like that I will users let the choice in specifying either a plain no-interface-view bean or other beans as well, but then supplemented with the interface name.